# CollectionFS image url from cfsFileUrl handler not working

Tags: meteor

I have followed collectionFS guide and several other stackoverflow questions [here][1], but I still face an error in displaying the image. The broken image icon is shown and console prints "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:". Any idea what i can do to solve this??

My code are as follows:

HTML

```
<template name="fileList">
    {{#each images}}
        {{name}}
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'default1'}}">
        <br />
    {{else}}
        No Files uploaded
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Client JS

```
Template.fileList.helpers({
    'images': function(){
        return ImagesFS.find({}, {sort: {uploadDate:-1}});
    }
});
```

Server JS

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    ImagesFS.fileHandlers({
      default1: function(options) { // Options contains blob and fileRecord — same is expected in return if should be saved on filesytem, can be modified
        console.log('I am handling default1: ' + options.fileRecord.filename);
         console.log(options.destination());
        return { blob: options.blob, fileRecord: options.fileRecord }; // if no blob then save result in fileHandle (added createdAt)
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: No help for the poor developer???):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cfs-public-folder
```

is not working anymore on 0.9.x

**please use:**

```
.url()
```

like

```
MyColletionCFS.findOne().url()
```

Answer (score 6):

I got this working by manually adding the cfs-public-folder package via:

```
meteor add cfs-public-folder
```

Now files show in the browser, and the URL to

```
http://localhost:3000/cfs/<collectionFS name>/<imageId_fileHandler.ext>
```

works.